# How can I have Numbers autofill interpolated values between two cells?

Tags: numbers

How can I have Numbers autofill interpolated values in a range of selected cells (from the value of the first cell to the value of the last cell)?

I know how to do this with a formula but it's too awkward as I do this quite frequently. Therefore, I would like to use the Autofill function, or similar. But it doesn't seem to be intelligent enough to interpolate.

Ex:
[7] […] […] […] [10]  ➾  [7] [7.75] [8.5] [9.25] [10]

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using the autofill feature that can be accessed only using a mouse or a keyboard shortcut in Numbers. (Technically, it is extrapolation but I reckon it would do the job.) An autofill feature is also available through the Numbers menu (Table -> Autofill Cells) but that one can not handle sequences.

For a range of cells in a column to be automatically filled in based on a sequence, first manually fill in at least the first two cells in the range. Then select those two cells, a.k.a. example cells, and move the mouse pointer over the bottom border of the example cells so that a yellow autofill handle (a dot) appears. Then hover the mouse pointer over the yellow handle so that the mouse pointer becomes a two-way arrow. When the two-way arrow appears, assuming you are right-handed, left-click on the mouse so that the outer borders of the example cells also turn into yellow and drag the yellow handle along with the two-way arrow over to the last cell of the range to be filled in and release the mouse. You can also have cells above the example cells automatically filled in as well as cells in a row.

As an example, take a look at the gif below (decimal points appear as commas because I use Continental Europe number formatting). Further details on the mouse-enabled autofill feature in Numbers as well as directions on accessing it using a keyboard shortcut are available in this Apple support webpage called "[Autofill cells in Numbers on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/numbers/autofill-cells-tan0e1129cf6/11.2/mac/1.0)".

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Alper. 

However, I'm not looking for the extrapolation function (that I know of) but an interpolation function like the one I described above. 
Counting the number of steps required to manually simulate interpolation is quite large, and therefore quite cumbersome. This is what I would like to avoid since I do this about 500 times every day, with various interpolation ranges.

Comment: I am afraid there is no standard feature in Numbers that would do exactly what you are looking for. What then you need to do is to write a small program in AppleScript towards Numbers and register it as a service (nowadays called a Quick Action) through Automator. See the video in  “[Using AppleScript To Automate In Numbers](https://macmost.com/using-applescript-to-automate-in-numbers.html)” for a brief introduction to AppleScript and Automator and the  "[iWork Automation: Numbers AppleScript Support](https://iworkautomation.com/numbers/)" webpage for further details.

Comment: Yes, I might try the scripting option later. Thanks for the advice and links, Alper.

Answer (score 0):

Addition for @Alper answer.

Autofill with keyboard and shortcut:

1. Select range;
2. Press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>;
3. Wide range with arrows.

Comment: This is still only autofill with extrapolation. I am looking for interpolation, as described in my comment above and in the title.